# Automatically request accessToken using Feign

Tags: jwt, access-token, feign

there are numerous posts explaining how to add dynamic header into request using Feign Interceptor

```
@Bean
public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
        var jwtToken = refreshAccessTokenClient.refresh();
        requestTemplate.header("Authorization", jwtToken);
    }
}
```

is there any possibility to share `jwtToken` across many threads and refresh in periodically? Current solution is sub-optimal and makes 1 extra call each time.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with solution:

```
@Bean
    public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor(@Value("${service.login}") String login,
                                                 @Value("${service.apiKey}") String apiKey) {
        return
                requestTemplate -> {
                    var request = LoginRequest.builder().loginId(login).apiKey(apiKey).build();
                    var jwtToken = authAuthProvider.login(request).getData().getAccessToken();
                    requestTemplate.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwtToken);
                };
    }
```

I blindly request jwtToken for every API call. It doesn't look like effective solution. Should look for some `@Cacheable` thing with TLL?